# Mongo filter not supported, Which uses for AddMonths to date

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I am trying to create a mongo filter which uses AddMonths to date

```
var filter = Builders<CustomerSubscription>.Filter.ElemMatch(y => y.SubscriptionOrders,x => x.SubscriptionEndDate.AddMonths(x.GracePerdateiod) < DateTime.UtcNow);
```

{document}{SubscriptionEndDate}.AddMonths(3) is not supported.